# Coreplot - stretchable Images

Tags: core-plot

I was not able to find any example nor any other question regarding stretchable images in CorePlot. I'm trying to use an annotation in my graph whose image must be a stretchable one (the corners of the image must be untouched).

I set the `fill` of the annotation with `fillWithImage:` and I think I'm right on that spot, but the image is resizing itself completely, stretching the corners as well.

I tried all the combinations with `UIImage` and `CPTImage` that I know of or have seen. But to no avail.

One example is:

```
 UIImage *annotationImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:13 topCapHeight:12];
 CPTFill *annotationFill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:[CPTImage imageWithCGImage:annotationImage.CGImage]];
 borderLayer.fill = annotationFill;
```

Please tell me this is possible and I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported in the current version of Core Plot. Please open an enhancement request on the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).